# Database Connection error

Tags: sql, winforms, connection

I have win application and i get this error when i want to connect the database to my app
error:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Aren\Desktop\DB\REGISTRATION.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

```
public class DALBase
{
    protected SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Aren\\Desktop\\DB\\REGISTRATION.mdf;integrated Security=true ; User Instance=True");
    protected SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    protected SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    protected DataSet ds = new DataSet();

}
```

---

```
public DataSet GetStudent(string filter)
    {

        DataSet dset = new DataSet();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            string cmdstring = string.Format("Select * from {0}"
               , Common.Data.Student.Table_Name);


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter)) cmdstring += " where " + filter;


            cmd.CommandText = cmdstring;
            cmd.Connection = this.con;
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = cmdstring;
            cmd.Connection = this.con;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dset, Common.Data.Student.Table_Name);
            return dset;
        }
    }
```

NOTE: ALSO i got 3 project in my solution the DALBASE and GETSTUDENT methods are in one project and i call them from other project to get the data for me.

Comment: I don't know, but I'm puzzled by the use of both single and double slashes in the connection string. Does it need \\ in the windows path?

Answer (score 0):

I believe i have encountered this problem in the past. in my situation I loaded an application in visual Studio which when run would load a database and attach to SQL Server. Somehow when I closed the application it didn't deattach the database from SQL SERVER and next time I ran the app it complained with a similar if not the same message.

If you have SSMS installed open up to the .\SQLEXPRESS instance and see if you have a Registration*.mdf file attached. Or if you don't have SSMS open up your command line and type...

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -Q "select name from sys.databases"
```

This will show you all your databases attached/online on that instance.

Hope this helps.